# Cordova resolveLocalFileSystemURL unresolved function or method

Tags: cordova, cordova-3

My console is filled with:

```
resolveLocalFileSystemURI is deprecated. Please call resolveLocalFileSystemURL instead.
```

when I change to resolveLocalFileSystemURL my IDE throws up a unresolved function or method warning

My version if Cordova is 3.5.0-0.2.6. and the file plugin is 
org.apache.cordova.file 1.3.1 "File"

Comment: Looks like when I compile the code it works, wonder why my IDE can't find the method.